# MS SQL Server 2014 is not able to connect to Coldfusion 11

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have Coldfusion 11 installed on my Laptop (Windows 8.1 Pro) and MS SQL Server 2014 but unable to get them talking to one another. Here are the three screenshots for your reference, please let me know if I am doing something wrong:

For CF Administrator:

[image]

For SQL Server Management Studio

[image]

Data Source:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message clearly says, that the error is due to Authentication failure. You need to enable [Mixed-mode authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188670.aspx). Once enabled, try to login and check the error message, if fails again. Try restarting SQL Server/Agent service with windows authentication credentials, to validate that there is no problem.

Alternatively, try skipping the username/password in CF Admin and connect. You may then specify them at the query level as well.

Comment: Thanks, changing it to SQL Server & Windows Authentication (Mixed Mode) helped.